# How to bind to a custom ip address and port number in HTML Websockets API?

Tags: html, web

I am new to HTML5 Websockets API and an amateur in javascript.
As far as i have seen, a new socket is created using a Websocket constructor sort of thing. For example :-

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9998/echo");
```

There is no command to specify the IP address and port number to which the new websocket on the client is supposed to bind to.

So is it possible to specify a custom ip:port combination or does the browser just randomly assigns a port number to the new socket?

Answer (score 0):

In your example the port is 9998. The localhost could be replaced by the desired ip.

Comment: Isn't that the port on server side? I want to use custom port on client side